# How to use super with arguments

Tags: python, inheritance, dynamic, super

I have linear hierarchy of classes, `A`, `B`, `C`, sharing a method with a different implementation which depends on the result of the father's one. Such methods have *same identifier* but different signature and belongingness (static, class, instance).

Since I am working with *dynamic* object creation I need to call `super` with its ["full" signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)... and here the problems arise.

The *zero argument form* works perfectly:

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def m(): return 'A.m()'

class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def m(cls):
        return super().m() + ' ... & from B.m()'
    
class C(B):
    def m(self, text):
        return super().m() + f' ... & from C().m("{text}")'


print(C().m("XXX"))
```

but if I try to add arguments

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def m(): return 'A.m()'

class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def m(cls):
        return super(cls, cls).m() + ' ... & from B.m()' # <- raise RecursionError
    
class C(B):
    def m(self, text):
        return super(type(self), self).m() + f' ... & from C().m("{text}")'

print(C().m("XXX"))
```

the compiler complains

```
File "path_to_file.py", line XY, in m
  return super(cls, cls).m() + ' ... & from B.m()'
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Previous line repeated 995 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I tried different combinations without success.

What is the right way to call `super(?, ?).m()`?

---

Here a further **abstraction** of the above problem with same issue:

```
class A:
    def m(self):
        return f"A().m from {type(self).__name__}()"
class B(A):
    def m(self):
        return super(?, ?).m() + f" & B().m from {type(self).__name__}()"
class C(B):
    def m(self):
        return super(type(self), self).m() + f" & C().m from {type(self).__name__}()"


print(C().m())
#A().m from C() & B().m from C() & C().m from C()
```

Comment: I would like to know (ideally) how to fix it and/or have a better understanding of `super` and class namespaces

Comment: If the method of `BB` is turned to static **and** manually pass the parameters to `super` then it works: `staticmethod(lambda: compile(getattr(super(BB, BB), k)()))`, but this is almost the original problem:(

Comment: Question edited: new reformulation

Comment: It is very poor practice to have a single identifier in a class hierarchy have dramatically different behaviors.  It violates the "principle of least surprise", and will make the code much more difficult to maintain.  You should abandon this effort and find a more traditional and maintainable way to do what you need.

Comment: @ Tim Roberts thanks for the info, I also had that feeling: if you label all methods with a distinct identifier the issue is over, but I would like to understand what's going on... and how should look like the `super(?, ?).m()`:)

Comment: When calling `m` from `C` it triggers the parent method which is implemented in `B` with `super(cls, cls).m()`. This cause a recursion error because the `cls` in `B` represents the class from which it's called, `C`, and gives raise to a _self-referential_ loop. This a small fix but still far from the solution

Comment: What is the problem with the "zero argument" example that is shown first? I didn't understand why you can't use that (you write you can't because you "try to add arguments", but why?).

Comment: My goal is to _translate_ the static code into dynamic (using `type`) but for that I need a full signature, from the doc _"The zero argument form only works inside a class definition"_

Comment: if you try to generate the classes dynamically with `super()` you will get `RuntimeError: super(): __class__ cell not found`

Answer (score 0):

Study first the result of *zero argument form*

```
class A:
    def m(self):
        return f"A().m from {type(self).__name__}()"
class B(A):
    def m(self):
        return super().m() + f" & B().m from {type(self).__name__}()"
class C(B):
    def m(self):
        return super().m() + f" & C().m from {type(self).__name__}()"


print(C().m())
```

The method `m` called from the child class `C` "spreads" among the parents classes and triggers the corresponding method `m`.
Before calling such method also another operation take place: the substitution of `self` with the `self` of the object from which the call was originated, `C` in this case.

This fact can be seen from the expected result

```
A().m from C() & B().m from C() & C().m from C()   # the effect of the subsitutions
           ^^^              ^^^              ^^^
```

This explain also why `super(type(self), self).m` called from `B` raises an `RecursionError`: it is executed as smt like `super(C, C()).m`.

A possible fix will be to find a way to *freeze* the reference of the class inside the method to avoid such substitution.
Here an example with `locals()`

```
class A:
    def m(self):
        return f"A().m from {type(self).__name__}()"
class B(A):
    def m(self):
        this_cls = locals()['__class__']
        return super(this_cls, self).m() + f" & B().m from {type(self).__name__}()"
class C(B):
    def m(self):
        this_cls = locals()['__class__'] # for "steril" class is not needed -> super(type(self), self) is ok
        return super(this_cls, self).m() + f" & C().m from {type(self).__name__}()"
```

This approach solves the problem in the *static* setting (and hope it exists more rigorous ones!)... but it's **not** compatible for *dynamic* programming!